# CAS proxy with Laravel Homestead: callback url not authenticated

Tags: php, laravel, cas

I need to set up a Laravel app that can proxy authenticate into a third party service (that I also have control over) using CAS 2.0 protocol.

For this I have:

- A CAS server running on a local Docker container that is configured to let through all services in HTTP and HTTPS
- The laravel app running on a local homestead vm (I mapped 127.0.0.1 to homestead.app)
- The third party app (a Django-based python app) also running locally via runserver that's I'll need to make authenticated requests to (so I need to have the laravel app as proxy that will then make requests to this app).

The laravel app use jasig/phpCAS and xavrsl/cas (not enough reputation to post more than 2 links, but the github repos come up easy via Google) to interact with the CAS server. It's an extremely simple app that just displays a message when the user is succesfully logged in via CAS. The simplicity is because I only have to set this up for testing purpose for further developments.

So far, I have managed to make non-proxy authentication work, so all parts of my setup are interacting and communicating correctly.

However it all goes to hell when I want to enable proxy authentication. I can't generate the PGT ticket that the Laravel App would use to make authenticated requests on behalf of the user. Apparently the CAS server refuses to recognize the validity of the pgtURL callback (which by default needs to be https, but self signed certificates don't seem to be enough). As all this will only be used for testing purpose I have disabled SSL validation from the CAS server as per [this post](http://www.codemarvels.com/2010/12/how-to-do-cas-sso-without-ssl/) and I try to make a http callback url work.

Here's the log when I try to connect to my server:

```
A126 .START phpCAS-1.3.3 ****************** [CAS.php:438]
A126 .=> phpCAS::proxy('2.0', '192.168.59.103', 8443, 'cas') [Sso.php:76]
A126 .|    => CAS_Client::__construct('2.0', true, '192.168.59.103', 8443, 'cas', true) [CAS.php:384]
A126 .|    |    Starting a new session ST-1-xVZCKeoYtmvKJzVQBTvQ-cas01exampleorg [Client.php:906]
A126 .|    |    Ticket 'ST-6-9sc0uCM1IJ1PwJiKJ9iT-cas01.example.org' found [Client.php:988]
A126 .|    <= ''
A126 .<= ''
A126 .=> phpCAS::setNoCasServerValidation() [Sso.php:98]
A126 .|    You have configured no validation of the legitimacy of the cas server. This is not recommended for production use. [CAS.php:1553]
A126 .<= ''
A126 .=> CAS_Client::handleLogoutRequests(true, false) [CAS.php:1193]
A126 .|    Not a logout request [Client.php:1689]
A126 .<= ''
A126 .=> phpCAS::allowProxyChain(CAS_ProxyChain) [Sso.php:111]
A126 .<= ''
A126 .=> phpCAS::setExtraCurlOption(81, 0) [AppServiceProvider.php:27]
A126 .<= ''
A126 .=> phpCAS::setFixedCallbackURL('http://homestead.app:8000') [AppServiceProvider.php:28]
A126 .<= ''
A126 .=> phpCAS::setPGTStorageFile('/home/vagrant/Code/storage/PGT.txt') [AppServiceProvider.php:29]
A126 .|    => CAS_PGTStorage_File::__construct(CAS_Client, '/home/vagrant/Code/storage/PGT.txt') [Client.php:2516]
A126 .|    |    => CAS_PGTStorage_AbstractStorage::__construct(CAS_Client) [File.php:119]
A126 .|    |    <= ''
A126 .|    <= ''
A126 .<= ''
A126 .=> phpCAS::forceAuthentication() [Sso.php:126]
A126 .|    => CAS_Client::forceAuthentication() [CAS.php:1015]
A126 .|    |    => CAS_Client::isAuthenticated() [Client.php:1245]
A126 .|    |    |    => CAS_Client::_wasPreviouslyAuthenticated() [Client.php:1356]
A126 .|    |    |    |    neither user nor PGT found [Client.php:1569]
A126 .|    |    |    <= false
A126 .|    |    |    CAS 2.0 ticket `ST-6-9sc0uCM1IJ1PwJiKJ9iT-cas01.example.org' is present [Client.php:1406]
A126 .|    |    |    => CAS_Client::validateCAS20('', NULL, NULL) [Client.php:1409]
A126 .|    |    |    |     [Client.php:3101]
A126 .|    |    |    |    => CAS_Client::getServerProxyValidateURL() [Client.php:3105]
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    => CAS_Client::getURL() [Client.php:507]
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    |    Final URI: http://homestead.app:8000/home [Client.php:3466]
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    <= 'http://homestead.app:8000/home'
A126 .|    |    |    |    <= 'https://192.168.59.103:8443/cas/proxyValidate?service=http%3A%2F%2Fhomestead.app%3A8000%2Fhome'
A126 .|    |    |    |    => CAS_Client::_readURL('https://192.168.59.103:8443/cas/proxyValidate?service=http%3A%2F%2Fhomestead.app%3A8000%2Fhome&ticket=ST-6-9sc0uCM1IJ1PwJiKJ9iT-cas01.example.org&pgtUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fhomestead.app%3A8000', NULL, NULL, NULL) [Client.php:3118]
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    => CAS_Request_CurlRequest::sendRequest() [AbstractRequest.php:242]
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    |    Response Body: 
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    |    
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    |    
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    |    
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    |    <cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    |        <cas:authenticationFailure code='INVALID_PROXY_CALLBACK'>
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    |            The supplied proxy callback url &#039;http://homestead.app:8000&#039; could not be authenticated.
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    |        </cas:authenticationFailure>
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    |    </cas:serviceResponse>
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    |     [CurlRequest.php:84]
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    <= true
A126 .|    |    |    |    <= true
A126 .|    |    |    |    => CAS_AuthenticationException::__construct(CAS_Client, 'Ticket not validated', 'https://192.168.59.103:8443/cas/proxyValidate?service=http%3A%2F%2Fhomestead.app%3A8000%2Fhome&ticket=ST-6-9sc0uCM1IJ1PwJiKJ9iT-cas01.example.org&pgtUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fhomestead.app%3A8000', false, false, '<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas=\'http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas\'>   <cas:authenticationFailure code=\'INVALID_PROXY_CALLBACK\'>     The supplied proxy callback url &#039;http://homestead.app:8000&#039; could not be authenticated.   </cas:authenticationFailure></cas:serviceResponse>', 'INVALID_PROXY_CALLBACK', 'The supplied proxy callback url \'http://homestead.app:8000\' could not be authenticated.') [Client.php:3209]
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    => CAS_Client::getURL() [AuthenticationException.php:76]
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    <= 'http://homestead.app:8000/home'
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    CAS URL: https://192.168.59.103:8443/cas/proxyValidate?service=http%3A%2F%2Fhomestead.app%3A8000%2Fhome&ticket=ST-6-9sc0uCM1IJ1PwJiKJ9iT-cas01.example.org&pgtUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fhomestead.app%3A8000 [AuthenticationException.php:79]
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    Authentication failure: Ticket not validated [AuthenticationException.php:80]
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    Reason: [INVALID_PROXY_CALLBACK] CAS error: The supplied proxy callback url 'http://homestead.app:8000' could not be authenticated. [AuthenticationException.php:96]
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    CAS response: 
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    <cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>
A126 .|    |    |    |    |     <cas:authenticationFailure code='INVALID_PROXY_CALLBACK'>
A126 .|    |    |    |    |         The supplied proxy callback url &#039;http://homestead.app:8000&#039; could not be authenticated.
A126 .|    |    |    |    |     </cas:authenticationFailure>
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    </cas:serviceResponse> [AuthenticationException.php:101]
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    exit()
A126 .|    |    |    |    |    -
A126 .|    |    |    |    -
A126 .|    |    |    -
A126 .|    |    -
A126 .|    -
```

I had the same message with https callback urls, that I know to be working (with self signed certificate) because I can access my laravel app using https. I didn't find anything in the CAS docs about how to configure CAS so the callback doesn't require a https url, and I did find very little help on the subject as a whole (according to this [walkthrough](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Proxy+CAS+Walkthrough), I fail at step 2(b), as getting the PGT is the first thing my app will want to do and it can't because the callback isn't authenticated).

Being very new to CAS (and Laravel/PHP), I'm not sure how to proceed from there and would appreciate a bit of help.

Comment: Here's a paste of the CAS config and the .env I used: http://pastebin.com/K92rMrpF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved it by adding my homestead self signed certificate into the docker container truststore. As the Cas server runs on a tomcat server, I had to use an alias to my homestead local ip by setting /etc/hosts here and there, which also caused its load of problem but they weren't that hard to fix anyway. I can expand on this if need be but I think my problem was far too specific to be relevant for many people.